# Elasticsearch multiple query values

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data

Hi I am trying to create a query with elastic search :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>co.elastic.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

I need the query to select multiple files based on values:

```
query = MatchQuery.of(m -> m
                        .field("fileType")
                        .query("EXP", "WAIT_EXP")
                    )._toQuery();
```

But this is giving me an syntax error. The query only gets 1 value. I need the get files with fileType both exp or wait_exp.

I read the documentation at here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/index.html but cant find anything helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bool query. Also you can check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55852787/how-to-do-bool-queries-in-elasticsearch-with-java-api).

```
SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest("your_index");

BoolQuery boolQuery = new BoolQuery();

boolQuery.should(MatchQuery.of(m -> m.field("fileType").query("EXP")));
boolQuery.should(MatchQuery.of(m -> m.field("fileType").query("WAIT_EXP")));

request.query(boolQuery);
```